# number of misses in spatial locality

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I am confused how the number of misses calculated in the example below (from **Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach**)

Example:

For the code below, determine which accesses are likely to cause data cache
misses. Next, insert prefetch instructions to reduce misses. Finally, calculate the
number of prefetch instructions executed and the misses avoided by prefetching.
Let’s assume we have an 8 KB direct-mapped data cache with 16-byte blocks,
and it is a write-back cache that does write allocate. The elements of a and b are 8
bytes long since they are double-precision floating-point arrays. There are 3 rows
and 100 columns for a and 101 rows and 3 columns for b. Let’s also assume they
are not in the cache at the start of the program.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i = i+1)
for (j = 0; j < 100; j = j+1)
a[i][j] = b[j][0] * b[j+1][0];
```

Answer:

The compiler will first determine which accesses are likely to cause cache
misses; otherwise, we will waste time on issuing prefetch instructions for data
that would be hits. Elements of a are written in the order that they are stored in
memory, so a will benefit from spatial locality: The even values of j will miss
and the odd values will hit. Since a has 3 rows and 100 columns, its accesses will
lead to 3 × (100/2), or **150** misses.

How 150 misses calculated or why divided 100 by 2?

Comment: You're probably meant to assume that the `double` elements are 8-byte aligned, so there's no possibility that a double will span across two cache lines.  Then the answer you quoted seems like a pretty reasonable explanation of why `3 x 100/2 = 150` is the answer.  Can you explain what part of that doesn't make to you? (BTW, real CPUs usually have HW prefetchers that notice sequential access patterns, instead of requiring software to run extra instructions for acceptable performance when looping an array.  As this example shows, tuning prefetch depends on knowing the cache characteristics.)

Comment: ```The even values of j will miss and the odd values will hit.``` this part not make sense to me.

Comment: A line is 16 bytes; the even `double`s are the first of a new line, the odd ones aren't.